# angular application throw an error on prod but work perfect on dev

Tags: angular, syncfusion

i have this table and is working perfect in debug but when i deply this throws this error "zs.a.createInput is not a function"

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Dimension</th>
        <th>Dependencia por defecto</th>
        <th>Observaciones</th>
        <th>Dependencia Efectiva</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of dependenciaDimensiones">
        <td>{{row.dimension.nombre}}</td>
        <td>{{row.dimension.tipoDependencia.nombre}}</td>
        <td>{{row.dimension.observacion}}</td>
        <td><ejs-numerictextbox  format='n2' [(value)]='row.dependenciaEfectiva'></ejs-numerictextbox></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And what is `zs.a.createInput`?

Comment: Check that the method is not private?

Comment: is .createInput a private method in another part of your code. I have seen this sometimes where it needs to be made public. Try a search in your editor for .createInput

Comment: createInput is not a fuction of my code, i think maybe is part of angular or syncfusion framework

Answer (score 1):

Since the reported issue is not reproducible, I have prepared a sample with the code snippet provided. You can get the sample from [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbmskl?file=default.html).

Also, ensure that the `node_modules` are properly installed in your application. Its recommended to delete the `node_modules` from your application, then clear the cache using `npm cache clean --force` command and install the node_modules again using `npm install` command.

If the issue persists, revert with the product version and a sample which reproduces the issue.